# How do I hide the mouse over effect and make it so items are not clickable in a Gridview?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

Given:

```
<GridView 
ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}"            
Margin="10,0"
SelectionMode="None" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>                    
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="130,10,30,10">                        
            <ListView x:Name="Command" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}"
                      Width="400"
                      Margin="0,120,0,0"                                  
                      SelectionMode="None"                                
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AreaTemplateSelector}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,-4,0,-5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

When a hover over the "GRIDVIEW" items they light up, and also I am able to click on them and move back. I have put the SelectionMode=None and IsItemClickEnabled=False but that does not seem to have any effect.

Screen shot
[image: Notice that the far right column is highlighted]

Comment: Have you tried setting `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
` in the `ListViewItem`

Comment: The Grid item is lighting up, thats the one I want to change.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this Link in MSDN

[Removing Hover and Selection in Listview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7a693a6c-06a6-4a5e-9fc5-bba01e386688/how-to-turn-off-highlight-on-hover-on-xaml-listview-item)

I am still looking for the manuall style edit of list view. if this satisfies your answer then  please reply. Else i am looking for it :)

try visual State Manager for both: Grid and List

**EDIT**

AND THIS CODE WORKED PROPERLY. I AM PASTING THE ENTIRE XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewSimple.ScenarioOutput1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle1" TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" To="NoSelectionHint"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                            <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                            <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                                <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="4" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
                                    <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                    <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="4" Opacity="0"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="Xg" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource GridViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Height="40" Opacity="0" Width="40">
                                                <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,9,0,0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>


    <Grid Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" Width="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <GridView x:Name="ItemGridView" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"

            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StoreFrontTileTemplate}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource StoreFrontGridItemsPanelTemplate}"
            BorderBrush="LightGray"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            BorderThickness="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            SelectionMode="None" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}"/>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Go ahead paste this and add `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle1}"` to your Grid View and Let me know :) I tested this . i have removed the story board for Pointer Over.

And one more thing you can also experiment by

1 -> Right Clicking on the GridView in Designer Mode.
2 -> Edit Additional Template
3 -> ItemContainerStyle -> Edit a Copy.

try Modify the pointer over for both Listview and Gridview. Thanks

Comment: I have made a correction since it seem to be ambiguous. The Grid items light up, and I don't want those to behave like that.

Comment: The blue selection box or the white faded grid item ??

Comment: See i Know this can be Done 

using the Visual State Here's a sample code. But the exact code I am still unable to find. you have to put it on for The grid view as well as List view

Comment: See the edit and the code. i hope you can proceed using the pointer pressed event.

Comment: It does seem to work. I think the key might be on the VirtualizingStackPanel but I can seem to find it.

Comment: Wait m going through it

Comment: Please see the Edit. I guess might help you :)